# Webpage loads in 'scrolled to bottom' state in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm testing out a simple coming soon webpage and everything seems to be working accordingly except one. When I open the website in a mobile device, it loads the website at the bottom of the page. I mean it is already scrolled at the bottom. Even if I check it at dev console mobile screen size, it is scrolled to the bottom.

It opens in small screen devices like this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

This is the site: [demo](https://test.codevion.com/)

I'm not able to post all the code here as I don't know which part of the code have issues. Also, please tell me if the demo site have performance issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove The `autofocus` property from `<input>` tag.

The `autofocus` property sets or returns whether a text field should automatically get focus when the page loads.

This property reflects the HTML autofocus attribute.

Please replace it

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" autofocus="off">
```

**BY**

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
```

Comment: Hey there. Thanks a lot for finding the issue. Made a stupid mistake lol. However, do you think the demo site have any performance issues? Like loading time, etc.